# Get the result of file count into a variable based on unix "Find" command

Tags: linux, unix

I am using the following command to get the result of file count into a variable based on unix "Find" command:
Criteria: number of files created today, with extension "tab" and size greater than 0
Command:

```
num_files_nz=$(find $src_file_path -type f -mtime 0 -name "*.tab" -size +0c | wc -l)

echo "Count of non-0KB files=${num_files_nz}"
```

This command works fine and returns a count of "4" from the command prompt (which is correct), but when I use the same command and the directory path within a shell script the count is returned as "0". 
I have tried entering the directory as in `$src_file_path` and then use "." instead of putting `$src_file_path` directly in the command.
I have put quotations to enclose the entire `$(find ...)` expression. 
But nothing works, it is always returning 0 count when used in a shell script.

I  would really appreciate if anybody can help me resolving this issue.

Following is the script:

```
#export path=/newitest/u01/app/itestcomn/admin/out/itest_eca1db11
#!/usr/bin/ --
request_id=$5
hostname=$6
username=$7
password=$8
email_to=${9}
org_code=${10}
dest_file_path="/$org_code"
RETCODE=0
echo "Main Request ID=$request_id"
echo "hostname=$hostname"
echo "username=$username"
echo "password=$password"
echo "email_to=$email_to"
echo "dest_file_path=$dest_file_path"
echo "org_code=$org_code"
cd $XXKE_TOP/../../keedi/11.5.0/outbound/"$org_code"
src_file_path="$(pwd)"
ls -l
echo "src_file_path=$src_file_path"
#number of files created today, with extension "tab" and size greater than 0
num_files_nz=$(find $src_file_path -type f -mtime 0 -name "*.tab" -size +0c | wc -l)
echo "Count of non-0KB files=${num_files_nz}"

#number of files created today, with name "StockTransfer_Oracle.tab" and size equals 0 
num_files_z=$(find $src_file_path -type f -mtime 0 -name "StockTransfer_Oracle.tab" -size 0c | wc -l)
echo "Count of 0KB files=${num_files_z}"

#total file count
num_tot_files=$(expr "$num_files_nz" + "$num_files_z")
echo "Total file count=${num_tot_files}"

if [ "$num_tot_files" -eq 14 ];
then
  echo "FTP Start"
  ftp -v -n $hostname <<EOF
  quote USER $username
  quote PASS $password
  cd /
  cd $dest_file_path
  pwd
  prompt off
  mput *.tab
  bye
EOF

else
  echo "ERROR GENERATING EXTRACTS"
  #Extract files with zero size other than the file "StockTransfer_Oracle.tab"
  err_files="$(find $src_file_path -type f -mtime 0 -name "*.tab" ! -name "StockTransfer_Oracle.tab" -size 0c)"
  echo "Error Ertracts"
  echo "${err_files}"
  msg_body="Following $org_code extracts were not completely generated:\n\n$err_files"
  echo ${msg_body} | mailx -s "ERROR: Extract File Generation"  ${email_to}
fi
```

I am entering the source directory by a "cd" command in line 18, I am using the same path as the value in the variable $src_file_path, and it the same path should be accessed when I am using "." in the find statement.
I will explore absolute path but please send some examples if possible and any other suggestions that might help make the shell script work.

Also when I am creating a ".sh" file and executing it from command prompt the find command works and returns the correct count but when I convert it to ".prog" and run it using a concurrent program the command returns a zero count

Thanks
Anir

Comment: Hello.I have tried as you described.But I get the correct answer(for me ,it's:Count of non-0KB files=1) whether i run it in command or in shell script file.So I want to know your exact shell script.

Comment: And which directory are you running the shell script file in when you use "." instead of putting $src_file_path?  And have you tried to use the absolute path?

Comment: If your `src_file_path` has spaces, you should put it in quotes i.e. `$(find "$src_file_path" ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.

cd $XXKE_TOP/../../keedi/11.5.0/outbound/"$org_code"
src_file_path="$(pwd)"

Instead I suggest you state is as below and it should be fixed:

export src_file_path=$XXKE_TOP/../../keedi/11.5.0/outbound/"$org_code"